# can't clean up setTimeout in useEffect unmount cleanup

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make kind of flash message displayer to display success, error, warning messages at the top for a certain duration.

I have made the use of useRef hook to store timeouts so that I can clear it incase component unmounts before timeout completion.

Everything works as expected except, if the component unmounts before timeout callback, it does not clear the timeout which indeed is trying to setState which gives

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'
import SuccessGreen from '../../assets/SuccessGreen.svg'
import Cross from '../../assets/Cancel.svg'
import WarningExclamation from '../../assets/WarningExclamation.svg'

const ICONS_MAP = {
    "warning": WarningExclamation,
    "success": SuccessGreen,
    "error": ""
}

export const FlashMessages = ({
    duration=5000,
    closeCallback,
    pauseOnHover=false,
    messageTheme='warning',
    typoGraphy={className: 'text_body'},
    firstIcon=true,
    ...props
}) => {
    const [isDisplayable, setIsDisplayable] = useState(true)
    const resumedAt = useRef(null)
    const remainingDuration = useRef(duration)    
    const countDownTimer = useRef(null)
    
    useEffect(() => {
        countDownTimer.current = resumeDuration()
        console.log(countDownTimer, "From mount")
        return () => {clearTimeout(countDownTimer.current)}
    }, [])

    const resumeDuration = () => {
        clearTimeout(countDownTimer.current)
        resumedAt.current = new Date()
        return setTimeout(() => forceCancel(), remainingDuration.current)
    }

    const pauseDuration = () => {
        if(pauseOnHover){
            clearTimeout(countDownTimer.current)
            remainingDuration.current = remainingDuration.current - (new Date() - resumedAt.current)
        }
    }
    
    const forceCancel = () => {
        console.log(countDownTimer, "From force")
        clearTimeout(countDownTimer.current);
        setIsDisplayable(false);
        closeCallback(null);
    }

    return isDisplayable ? (
        <div onMouseEnter={pauseDuration} onMouseLeave={resumeDuration}
            className={`flash_message_container ${messageTheme} ${typoGraphy.className}`} style={props.style}>
            {   firstIcon ? (<img src={ICONS_MAP[messageTheme]} style={{marginRight: 8, width: 20}} />) : null   }
            <div style={{marginRight: 8}}>{props.children}</div>
            <img src={Cross} onClick={forceCancel} style={{cursor: 'pointer', width: 20}}/>
        </div>
    ):null
}
```

I have tried to mimic the core functionality of this npm package
*https://github.com/danielsneijers/react-flash-message/blob/master/src/index.jsx*
but whith functional component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that when the `mouseleave` event happens, the timeout id returned by `resumeDuration` is not saved in `countDownTimer.current`, so the timeout isn't cleared in the cleanup function returned by `useEffect`.

You could modify `resumeDuration` to save the timeout id to `countDownTimer.current` instead of returning it:

```js
countDownTimer.current = setTimeout(() => forceCancel(), remainingDuration.current)
```

and then, inside `useEffect`, just call `resumeDuration`, so the component would look like this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'
import SuccessGreen from '../../assets/SuccessGreen.svg'
import Cross from '../../assets/Cancel.svg'
import WarningExclamation from '../../assets/WarningExclamation.svg'

const ICONS_MAP = {
    "warning": WarningExclamation,
    "success": SuccessGreen,
    "error": ""
}

export const FlashMessages = ({
    duration=5000,
    closeCallback,
    pauseOnHover=false,
    messageTheme='warning',
    typoGraphy={className: 'text_body'},
    firstIcon=true,
    ...props
}) => {
    const [isDisplayable, setIsDisplayable] = useState(true)
    const resumedAt = useRef(null)
    const remainingDuration = useRef(duration)
    const countDownTimer = useRef(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        resumeDuration()
        console.log(countDownTimer, "From mount")
        return () => {clearTimeout(countDownTimer.current)}
    }, [])

    const resumeDuration = () => {
        clearTimeout(countDownTimer.current)
        resumedAt.current = new Date()
        countDownTimer.current = setTimeout(() => forceCancel(), remainingDuration.current)
    }

    const pauseDuration = () => {
        if(pauseOnHover){
            clearTimeout(countDownTimer.current)
            remainingDuration.current = remainingDuration.current - (new Date() - resumedAt.current)
        }
    }

    const forceCancel = () => {
        console.log(countDownTimer, "From force")
        clearTimeout(countDownTimer.current);
        setIsDisplayable(false);
        closeCallback(null);
    }

    return isDisplayable ? (
        <div onMouseEnter={pauseDuration} onMouseLeave={resumeDuration}
            className={`flash_message_container ${messageTheme} ${typoGraphy.className}`} style={props.style}>
            {   firstIcon ? (<img src={ICONS_MAP[messageTheme]} style={{marginRight: 8, width: 20}} />) : null   }
            <div style={{marginRight: 8}}>{props.children}</div>
            <img src={Cross} onClick={forceCancel} style={{cursor: 'pointer', width: 20}}/>
        </div>
    ):null
}
```

and it would then mimic the logic from https://github.com/danielsneijers/react-flash-message/blob/master/src/index.jsx

Comment: Oh!! Got it. I think that's the issue, will try that